# OBJ-C: Core-Plot XY-Axis Fixing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-plot

I want to fix the axes so that they are always to the left hand side and bottom of my plot space. My current implementation is not enabling userInteraction so no need to worry about scrolling.

```
// Setup plot space
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;

// Axes
CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
//x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"0.5");
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0.5");
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
x.labelingPolicy = CPAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;

CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
//y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"0.5");
y.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
y.labelingPolicy = CPAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
```

...

```
//Auto scale the plot space to fit the data
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObject:boundLinePlot]];
CPPlotRange *xRange = plotSpace.xRange;
[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPDecimalFromDouble(1.25)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
CPPlotRange *yRange = plotSpace.yRange;
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPDecimalFromDouble(1.1)];
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
```

Edit:
I want to figure out how to fix my x-axis and y-axis to the bottom of the plot and left-hand side of the plot respectively. I don't have a SS but I basically want to display a graph with axes that are fixed in a predetermined position. Alternatively, is there a way to remove the x-axis altogether so I can just have a y-axis? If so, it is much easier to lock the y-axis in a fixed position.

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing? Perhaps a screen shot or a description of the behavior you observe given the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix in my edit. To remove the x axis simply do something like the following:

```
x.axisLineStyle = nil;
```

This tells core-plot not to render the line for the x-axis.

Comment: -1 because this answer does not answer the original question (which is a good one).